# Are feat extraordinary abilities?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, class-feature

I have not seen anything document in in the rules stating that a feat is an extraodinary ability.

I have seen it being categorised as a 'special feature' of the character.

This question has already been asked but with no RAW satisfactory answers IMO.   Has anyone really looked through all the core books, index words, the FAQ, Sage Advice, and [Rules of the Game](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/arch/rg) resources with no indications at all what feats as special abilities are categorised as?

Comment: If answers to the duplicate are unsatisfactory, consider a bounty on the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Abilities are split into Natural Abilities and Special Abilities.

Natural Abilities are abilities that come from the character/creature's nature.

Special Abilities are split into several classes:

- Supernatural (Su)
- Spell-Like Abilities (Sp)
- Extraordinary (Ex)

Feats and all other special features (excluding spells) are considered Natural Abilities unless specified otherwise (Su, Sp, Ex)

You can read more [here](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm)

Comment: Unfortunately, that reference is the special abilities section, it does not mention feats at all. If you look on a stat block, special abilities is a separate section from feats. It does not actually apply to feats, nor do feats stem from the physical nature of the creature, as natural abilities do.

Comment: @nijineko true, but it is pretty much all of the reliable information I know of on the matter. That feats aren't mentioned at all as Su, Sp, Ex says something

Comment: Fortunately for me, psionic feats were called out specifically as to which they are.